# Ember.js count position of object in Ember Data Model for simple pagination

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am tryin to count the position of an object. That means which numeric position an item has. That cannot be the primary key because they are not persistent; a record can get deleted.

Asume we have this "model" (a simple array for now, I use Ember Data):

```
posts = [
  {id: 4, number: 104, title: 'Post 4'},
  {id: 2, number: 102, title: 'Post 2'},
  {id: 3, number: 103, title: 'Post 3'},
];
```

So at to allow sorting in the **post*s*Controller** we do:

```
this.controllerFor('posts').set('sortProperties', ['id']); // or maybe just sorting on 'number'
this.controllerFor('posts').set('sortAscending', true);
```

In the template I want to show the current post and the total number of posts `{{currentPostCount}} of {{totalPostCount}}`

In **postController** I have the following computed properties:

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    posts: function () {
        return this.store.all('posts');
    }.property(),

    currentCount: function () {
        // if there is an id get the position of the record
        // that will be the position count of the post record
        var id = this.get('id');
        if (id) {
            console.log('this item has an id: ' + id);

            var count = 0;
            var currentCount;

            // loop over posts to check at which position the current post is
            this.get('posts').filter(function (item) {

                count++;
                if (item.id == id) {
                    console.log('yay id found! count is: ' + count)
                     currentCount = count;
                }
            });

            return currentCount;
        }
    }.property('posts.@each'),


    totalCount: function () {
        var posts= this.get('posts');
        return posts.get('length');
    }.property('posts.@each')
});
```

**Edit: add model:**

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        this.controllerFor('posts').set('model', this.store.find('post'));
        // sort posts by id
        this.controllerFor('posts').set('sortProperties', ['id']);
        //(...)
    }
});

App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
```

.

## **Update: full working simple pagination in Ember.js**

In your template:

```
 <div id="pagination">
      <span>Post {{index}}/{{totalCount}}</span>
      <a {{action previousPost this}} href="#">Previous</a>
      <a {{action nextPost this}} href="#">Next</a>
 </div>
```

The **PostsController**:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['id'], // I sort on ID, but you can sort on any property you want.
    sortAscending: true,

    assignIndex: function () {
        this.map(function (item, index) {
            Ember.set(item, 'index', index + 1)
        })
    }.observes('content.[]', 'firstObject', 'lastObject')

});
```

Actions in the PostController:

```
    previousPost: function (post) {
        var newIndex = (post.index - 1);
        var previousPost = this.store.all('post').findBy('index', newIndex);

        if (previousPost) {
            this.transitionToRoute('post', previousPost);
        }
    },

    nextPost: function (post) {
        var newIndex = (post.index + 1);
        var nextPost = this.store.all('post').findBy('index', newIndex);

        if (nextPost) {
            this.transitionToRoute('post', nextPost);
        }
    }
```

I have two computed properties in the PostController. However you can better use the following in your **PostsController** to do it the Ember way, like [kingpin2k said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568927/ember-js-count-position-of-object-in-ember-data-model-for-simple-pagination#comment30773464_20568927). Then you can also omit the posts property.

```
posts: function () {
    return this.store.all('posts');
}.property(),

// totalcount below the page for pagination
totalCount: function () {
    var posts= this.get('posts');
    return posts.get('length');
}.property('posts.@each'),
```

Comment: do you have a posts controller?

Comment: Yes, that is where the actions above live. I edit my question accordingly for you.

Comment: does the posts controller have all the posts as its backing model?

Comment: I have edited the question. For the model I also edit the above question. Edit: because I only need to show one post at a time, not all posts at once. I do the model like this. There is no Posts route. I only need Posts for showing in a select box or to count it, like I try.

Comment: Is there any reason you use find on the posts controller, bu all in the post? (aka the posts controller won't stay up to date)

Comment: Aha, it is not done to do things for Posts in the Post controller. I should do it in the Posts controller then. I try to get it done that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain an index on array content during sorting or removing objects.

**In PostsController:**

```
App.PostsController=Em.ArrayController.extend({
    assignIndex:function(){
        this.map(function(item,index){Em.set(item,'index',index+1)})
        }.observes('content.[]','firstObject','lastObject'),
            //other contents to follow...
```

In posts template the property index is available which is dynamically updated when adding or removing or sorting objects.

**In Posts Template:**

```
{{#each controller}}
        <p>{{index}}. {{name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, wow that is an easy way to add an index! Awesome! I update my question with everything I have implemented to get the simple pagination working.